# US phone number format on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add US phone number format without adding validation on form.
Eg: if user enters 805839483 in form, It should display (805) 583-9483 on shipping addresses.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add following changes for US phone number format on Checkout Page.

1. First, create **`checkout_index_index.xml`** file inside `app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\` folder and add this code:

   ```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" before="-" template="Vendor_Extension::inputformat.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
   ```

2.Then Add **`inputformat.phtml`** file inside `app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\` folder and add this code:

```
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"/></script>
<script>
    require([
        "jquery"
    ], function($) {
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                $('input[name$="telephone"]').inputmask({"mask": "+1(999) 999 99 99"});
            }, 6000);
    });
</script>
```

- Please Find Out Attached screenshots

[image: Checkout Page Address]

- Phone Number validation as per US Format on Edit Billing address

[image: Phone Number Validation]

- Phone Number validation as per US Format on the Shipping address
  [image: Shipping Address]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the Input Mask jQuery extension.

```
$('#phoneNumber').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
```

use this js for that:- jquery.inputmask.bundle.js